# Getting an Variable to Display at the top of an HTML Table Row

Tags: php, html, css

For the HTML table column below, the $count++ displays in the middle of the row.  How can I get it to display at the top of the row?

Thanks in advance,

John

Code:

```
echo '<td class="commentnamecount">'.$count++.'.</td>';
```

CSS:

```
.commentnamecount { width: 20px;
            overflow:hidden !important;
            color: #000000;
            vertical-align: 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
display:table-cell;   
vertical-align:top;
```

or

```
<td valign="top" class="commentnamecount">
```

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html